# How to see that separable metric space can be covered in a specific way?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be a separable metric space. How can I see that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist countably many balls ${K_j},j \in \mathbb{N}$, all having a radius equal to $\frac{1}{n}$, such that $S = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {\overline {{K_j}} } $, where  ${\overline {{K_j}} }$ denotes closure of ${{K_j}}$?

My attempt: Since $S$ is separable, there exists a countable set $\left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}$ such that $U \cap \left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\} \ne \emptyset $ for every open set $U \subseteq S$.

Obviously, $S = \bigcup\limits_{x \in S} {K\left( {x,\frac{1}{n}} \right)} $ and for each $x \in S$ there exists ${x_m}$ such that ${x_m} \in K\left( {x,\frac{1}{n}} \right)$.

If I could enumerate the set of balls $\left\{ {K\left( {x,\frac{1}{n}} \right):x \in S} \right\}$ by using $\left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}$ while preserving the covering property, I guess I would be one step closer to the solution.

I don't see how closure of the balls comes into play at the moment. How should I proceed? Is there an easier way to see that the statement holds?

Comment: What is $$\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{N}} K\left(x_m,\frac1n\right)\;?$$

Comment: Since ${x_m} \in K\left( {{x_m},\frac{1}{n}} \right)$, I can conclude that $\left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\} \subseteq \left\{ {K\left( {x,\frac{1}{n}} \right):x \in \left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}} \right\}$. It follows that $S = \overline {\left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}}  \subseteq \overline {\left\{ {K\left( {x,\frac{1}{n}} \right):x \in \left\{ {{x_m} \in S:m \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}} \right\}} $ from which the statement easily follows. Thanks

Comment: You don't even need the closures. Since $\{x_m\}$ is dense, every $x$ has distance less than $1/n$ from some $x_m$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it even easier